# Jquery get the id of clicked element and show hidden child div

Tags: php, jquery

i have an array of comments, and it should be possible to answer the comment.

```
<div>
<a href="#" class="answerBtn" id="<?=$comment->id ?>">Answer</a>
    <div id="answerDiv" style="display:none;">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?=$comment->id ?>"/>
                <p>
                     <label>Your name*</label>
                <br />
                     <input type="text" name="answer_username" id="answer_username" required />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Your Email (optional)</label>
                <br />
                        <input type="text" name="answer_email" />  
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Your comment*</label>
                <br />
                <textarea name="answer_message" required></textarea>
                </p>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?=base_url()?>" id="answer_baseurl"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Send"/>                             
                </form>
                </div>
```

i want to display the form when clicking the link, but because each comment has the same form i have to be specific, so i want to show the form depending on the id of the comment. so i tried something like this with jquery:

```
$('.answerBtn').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('id + div').slideToggle();
});
```

but that doesn't really work...

can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `div` to be displayed seems to be the next sibling, use `.next()` to find the element

```
$('.answerBtn').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line only cares about *tags* `id`:

```
$('id + div').slideToggle();
```

It does not use the variable `id` at all.

Instead, use the following:

```
$('#' + id + ' + div').slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way would be to assing same id to div which holds the form

```
<a href="#" class="answerBtn" id="<?=$comment->id ?>">Answer</a>

<div id="answerDiv_<?=$comment->id ?>" style="display:none;"> ... </div>
```

Then show a corresponding `div` when `.answerBtn` is clicked:

```
$('.answerBtn').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('div#answerDiv_'+id).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the id of the comment to *div* also like:

```
 <div id="answerDiv<?=$comment->id ?>" style="display:none;">
```

and in the script, try

```
 $('.answerBtn').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#answerDiv'+id).slideToggle();
 });
```